# Why class needs access modifiers?

Tags: c#

As I understand, with **private** modifier you can only inherit from a class, but you can not create instances of it.

```
private class A // error
{

}

class B
{
    static int Main()
    {
        A obj = new A();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Is it the only useful feature of the private classes?

Comment: You can create an instance of a private inner class

Comment: you can not create `class` with `private` access modifier

Comment: `private class` is not even accepted by the compiler except for inner classes. The keyword to allow inheriting, but disallow creating instances, is `abstract`.

Comment: I don't get it. Can you rephrase your question? What do you meant by *with private modifier you can only inherit from a class, but you can not create instances of it* ?

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi You can, if it is nested class

Comment: why did you need a private class in the first place?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: yes,thanks,i forgot to mention that.

Comment: @hvd Yes, I know. I wanted to know what the most commonly used of the private classes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We need access modifiers, because the different types in our assembly have different purposes of use. For instance an assembly will conclude at least one `public` class, which will be consumed by the user of the assembly. On the other hand, you may need to declare classes that will be used only inside your assembly and in the same namespace. So for this reason, you have to declare them as `private`. Last but not least  there would be types that should be accessible from all the other types in your assembly. Hence, you have to declare them as `internal`. In a few words, each type has different purpose of existence and subsequently different usage. For that reason they should have also different access modifier.

**NOTE** By default the access modifier for a class is internal.

Comment: `So you have to declare them as internal` or you can mention -> by default access modifier for class is `internal`.

Comment: Yeap, I do know that by I wanted to show the use of internal. Thanks for mentioning this.

Comment: By default the access modifier for a class is internal unless it is  **nested** .